# Url.Action parameters?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-2, url.action

In listing controller I have,

```
 public ActionResult GetByList(string name, string contact)
 {        
     var NameCollection = Service.GetByName(name);    
     var ContactCollection = Service.GetByContact(contact);           
     return View(new ListViewModel(NameCollection ,ContactCollection));
 }
```

In ASPX page I call,

```
 <a href="<%:Url.Action("GetByList","Listing" , new {name= "John"} , new {contact="calgary, vancouver"})%>"><span>People</span></a>
```

I have a problem in the ASPX code... I can pull the records for the name john. but when I give the `contact="calgary, vancouver"`, the webpage goes to error.

How can I call two parameters in the `Url.Action`.  I tried the below but that seems wrong too.

```
  <a href="<%:Url.Action("GetByList","Listing" , new {name= "John" , contact= " calgary, vancouver" })%>"><span>People</span></a>
```

Answer (score 249, accepted):

The following is the correct overload (in your example you are missing a closing `}` to the `routeValues` anonymous object so your code will throw an exception):

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("GetByList", "Listing", new { name = "John", contact = "calgary, vancouver" }) %>">
    <span>People</span>
</a>
```

Assuming you are using the default routes this should generate the following markup:

```
<a href="/Listing/GetByList?name=John&amp;contact=calgary%2C%20vancouver">
    <span>People</span>
</a>
```

which will successfully invoke the `GetByList` controller action passing the two parameters:

```
public ActionResult GetByList(string name, string contact) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @user787788, what problem are you getting? What do you mean *not accepting two parameters*? Who is not accepting? Are you getting an error message? Is your controller action not hit? Are you getting wrong values? Be specific.

Comment: When i give two parameters, the aspx page is not even hitting the controller. its finding the error in the page itself. i have a defalut exception called something gone worng. the aspx goes there

Comment: @user787788, what is the error? Exact message you are getting?

Comment: the error is , you may have typed the address (URL) incorrectly.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, i know this is a *very* old post, but i saw you were online. I don't suppose you'd know how to pass a parameter dynamically (not hardcoded like "John")?

Comment: @user3913686 Here is an example of what you can place in your view file: '@Url.Action("GetOverviewAsDocument", "FileAssignment", new { customerId = ViewData["customerId"] } )'

Answer (score 14):

This works for MVC 5:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { paramName1 = item.paramValue1, paramName2 = item.paramValue2 })" >
    Link text
</a>
```

Comment: What is item, as in item.paramValue1?

Comment: item.paramValue1 could be any text/string you want

Answer (score 4):

you can returns a private collection named HttpValueCollection even the documentation says it's a NameValueCollection using the ParseQueryString utility. 
Then add the keys manually, HttpValueCollection do the encoding for you.
And then just append the QueryString manually :

```
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(""); 
qs.Add("name", "John")
qs.Add("contact", "calgary");
qs.Add("contact", "vancouver")

<a href="<%: Url.Action("GetByList", "Listing")%>?<%:qs%>">
    <span>People</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple way to do it

```
<a class="nav-link"
   href='@Url.Action("Print1", "DeviceCertificates", new { Area = "Diagnostics"})\@Model.ID'>Print</a>
```

Where is `@Model.ID` is a parameter

And here there is a second example.

```
<a class="nav-link"
   href='@Url.Action("Print1", "DeviceCertificates", new { Area = "Diagnostics"})\@Model.ID?param2=ViewBag.P2&param3=ViewBag.P3'>Print</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following at  ASP.Net MVC

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetByList", "Listing",new {area = "Admin"})'
+ @Model.Id + '?name ="John"&contact ="calgary, vancouver"'+'"'>
    <span>People</span>
</a>
```