# how to get returned JSON data in MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am returning a simple data to ajax call. But I trying show that returned in alert is showing `undefined`. How can I get return JSON data?

```
   return Json(new { message = "success", url = Url.Action("Index", "Image") },
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

view

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/Admin/Image/UploadFiles',
                    autoUpload: true,
                    done: function (e, data) {
                        alert(data.message); //showing undefined
                        if (data.message== 'success') {
                            alert(data.message);
                            window.location = "www.google.com";
                        }
                    },
                    fail: function(e, data) {
                        console.write(data.errorThrown);
                    }
                })
```

Comment: what if you alert the whole data returned? is it undefined too?

Comment: i think the url is wrong

Comment: Use your debuggers (e.g. Chrome tools or whatever). Make the ajax call, look in the Network pane for the response. Is the response code 200? Have have look at the response, has it returned json data?

Comment: This may help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278694/url-action-parameters

Comment: I just did `alert(data)`, got `[object] [object]`

Comment: It works with @AaronLS solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the complete or success property?  You are confusing the xhr object's `.done()` with ajax setup property `complete:` or `success:` I think.

Done's second parameter is a status, not the data.

Try this instead

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Admin/Image/UploadFiles',
                autoUpload: true,
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    alert(data.message); 
                    if (data.message== 'success') {
                        alert(data.message);
                        window.location = "www.google.com";
                    }
                }
            })
```