# How can I make the following button call the GET method and not the POST method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following button:

```
<a id="commons" href="#" onclick="$('#sideViewAside').load('@Url.Action("PurchaseOrderSideView")', {orderId: '@item.OrderId'});" data-ma-action="sidebar-open" data-ma-target="#detailsTab" class="hidden-xs ma-trigger btn btn-icon command-edit waves-effect waves-circle"><span class="zmdi zmdi-view-list"></span></a>
```

My `Controller` has both the `GET` and `POST` method. When I run the code, on clicking this button, the POST method is being called, whereas, I want the GET method to be called. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're including data. That triggers a POST. If you want a GET, you need to use the query string parameters.

Comment: Oh. But I need to pass `orderId` to my `GET` method as it is the input parameter for my `GET` method. How to add that?

Comment: If you want a GET, you need to use the query string parameters. I believe there's an overload of `Url.Action()` that lets add parameters, as in this question: [Url.Action parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6278694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this code sending request with `Post`, it is caused by that you pass object to `.load` function. For [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), its default method is `Get`, but it will use `Post` if you use with object.

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

You could try code below to use `Get` with `orderId` as input.

```
<a id="commons" href="#" 
  onclick="$('#sideViewAside')
  .load('@Url.Action("PurchaseOrderSideView",
  new {orderId = "111"})')" data-ma-action="sidebar-open" data-matarget="#detailsTab"
class="hidden-xs ma-trigger btn btn-icon command-edit waves-effect waves-circle">
<span class="zmdi zmdi-view-list">Test1</span>
```