# How to load data from datatable in new view for editing?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, datatable

I have a view to display data from database into datatable. In table, I have edit, delete and detail options to do those respective functions.

My edit and details views are different pages(views). 
Now when I click row number 2's edit or delete, it takes me to that edit/details page, but there is no data loaded in those page text boxes.

My codes and designs below:

codes for loading datatable:

```
function SearchCategory(){
    $('#tblCategory').DataTable({
        "processing": false,
        "serverSide": false,
        "searchable": false,
        "ajax": {
            url: '@Url.Action("GetValues")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataSrc: 'data',
        },
        "columns": [{ data: "CategoryId" },
                { data: "Description" },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) { return '<a class="text-center" href="/Master/CategoryDetails?id="' + row.CategoryId + '"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>'; }
                },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) { return '<a class="text-center" href="/Master/CategoryEdit?id="' + row.CategoryId + '"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>'; }
                },
                {
                    data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="#" class="text-center" onclick=DeleteData("' + row.CategoryId + '"); ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
                }
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

table design:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%;" id="tblCategory" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
    <thead>
        <tr class="gridheader">                                              
            <td style="width: 30%;" class="search_field" search_field_value="CategoryId">Category Id</td>
            <td style="width: 30%;" class="search_field" search_field_value="Description">Description</td>
            <td style="width: 20%;" class="search_field" search_field_value="Details">Details</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;" class="text-center">Edit</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;" class="text-center">Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Design of my table:

[image]

When I click Edit or details Icon in each row it must take me to their respected edit/details page, it does, but respected datas not loaded in the edit/detail page text boxes.

Sample edit page design:

[image]

Each detail and edit page are in different views: I tried something like the following in their script .

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtCategoryId").text = row.CategoryId;
        $("#txtDescription").text = row.Description;

    });
</script>
```

But its not working how to do this. also How to delete selected row? Kindly help.TIA.

Comment: `text()` is a function....but it looks like you need `val(variable)` for `<input>`

Comment: even if change to val() also not working

Comment: Any errors in console? how is `row` defined?

Comment: no error come out, that makes me too confused as I am new to this MVC, cant able to search output as there is no error

Comment: Can you show the `Master` controller method `CategoryEdit` where you are passing the data

Comment: In categoryedit controller I didnt pass any code,  just return  view, as I am trying to pass code via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For your href in the a tag of the SearchCategory function, try this :

```
href="@url.Action("CategoryDetails","Master", new { id = row.CategoryId })"
```

-> Do the same thing for the CategoryEdit href.

Then, make sure your functions (CategoryEdit and CategoryDetails) take an id as a parameter and send the model of the specified id to the proper view!

The views should have something like `@model Category` at the beginning of the files.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6278737/4094893) as reference

---

EDIT :

In the views, you have to change

`row.CategoryId` => `@this.Model.CategoryId`

AND

`row. Description` => `@this.Model.Description`

and I repeat, It's crucial for your view's files to start with `@model Category`

SEE THIS LINK : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: when I use ur code it shows the error- the name 'row' doesnot exist in the current context..

Comment: sry it still not working for me. even  I added @method to all edit/detail and main view page too

Comment: @Riya Can you add the controller and the 2 views in your question?